# Remove the duplicate from the array (Deep Copy) Java

Tags: java

```
 public static boolean testGetUniqueCheckedOutItems() {
    String[] items = new String[]{"Carrot","Chicken","Chicken", "Tomato", "Onion","Carrot","Tomato"};
    int size = 7;
    String[] empty = {};
   getUniqueCheckedOutItems(items,size,empty));



 
public static int getUniqueCheckedOutItems(String[] items, int size, String[] itemsSet) {

    itemsSet = new String [items.length];


    for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        itemsSet[i] = items[i];
    }

    for (int i=itemsSet.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if (itemsSet[i].equals(itemsSet[j])) {
               size--;
            }

      }
        return size;
    }
```

The code supposes to return the size which remove the duplicates in array. However, it suppose not to remove both duplicate, but just one. So in here, since duplicates are "carrot, chicken,tomato" Thus, it suppose to return 4. However, it only return 6.

Can anyone help me to solve this?
I been on this problem for like an hour and half now

Comment: is this for homework? have you tried hashing the strings to count how many are unique?

Comment: Yea it is for my class and I havent learn hashing yet...

Comment: As long as return statement is within the outer `for` loop, code will not compile. If it's in the end of `getUniqueCheckedOutItems` method, it returns 4.

Comment: Omg... Thank you so so much... Ah... man this sucks...

Comment: I wasted for like almost 2hours for this minor problem

Comment: Do u see any other problems in my code which might cause some error?

Comment: Actually I don't understand why you pass size param, emty string param. If you have a task to figure out size of given array without duplicates, I would create a `HashSet` and return size of it. But since it's your homework I don't know whether you can use `HashSet`

Comment: "I wasted for like almost 2hours for this minor problem":  Welcome to programming.  This is how it is. Details count. It takes time to find all the details, especially when learning.  Which is why you did NOT waste your time. You learned more than you realize.  The more you make painful mistakes and overcome them the sooner you will become a good programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has several syntax errors so I'm not sure how you are obtaining any output.

- The method `testGetUniqueCheckedOutItems()` does not have a closing brace
- The method `getUniqueCheckedOutItems()` does not have a closing brace
- and the method `getUniqueCheckedOutItems(items,size,empty));` has an unexpected closing parenthesis.

The reason you would be getting the wrong value is that the return statement is inside of the `outer` for loop. So you prematurely return `size`.  Did you incorrectly enter your code?